# How to put every value from the column into the formula? (And make new column with results)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with columns like this:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.01784 | 90.12232 | 0.12323 |
| 36.50000 | 1.32003 | 30.10937 |
| -187.03982 | -1.09322 | -3.20091 |

And a formula like this:

y = ((maximum  - minimum)**2) + ((x - 10)**2), where

maximum = the maximum value in the column

minimum = the minimum value in the column

x = input value from the column (each cell one by one)

y = output value (the result for each cell)

The question is:
How can I put every new value from column into X, receive Y and make it for each column?
The result should be like:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50070.40824 | 14739.86089 | 1207.12533 |
| 50672.30112 | 8395.61661 | 1513.96151 |
| 88794.74179 | 8443.33426 | 1283.83877 |

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.sub(10).pow(2).add(df.max().sub(df.min()).pow(2))
```

Or:

```
(df-10)**2 + (df.max()-df.min())**2
```

Output:

```
       Column 1      Column 2     Column 3
0  50070.408244  14739.860900  1207.125339
1  50672.301126   8395.616617  1513.961515
2  88794.741791   8443.334267  1283.838779
```

Comment: Oh wow, so simple, thanks! I thought I will need cycles and functions :)

Comment: @Anna whenever possible, you can use vectorial operations, this is the most efficient ;)